# Display the value of button in the text box and change the color of the selected button in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to display the button value in the textbox and I want to change the background color of the selected button. Here is the code. Displaying the button value in the textbox  works fine but how to change background color of the selected button

```
<div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" id="display" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button" >
      <div class="input-group-btn">
      
    
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
          <button type="button" class="dropdown-item" value="1000">1000</button>
          
          <button type="button" class="dropdown-item" value="2000">2000</button>
          <div role="separator" class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <button type="button" class="dropdown-item" value="3000">3000</button>
          <div role="separator" class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <button type="button" class="dropdown-item" option value="4000">4000</button>
        
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div><br><br>
<input name="submit" type ="submit" value="click to submit">
<input name="reset" type ="reset" value="Reset">
</fieldset>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-item')
var textbox = document.getElementById('display')

for (let i=0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        textbox.value = e.target.value
    })
}
</script>
```

Comment: Do you want that background color to disappear again when another button is clicked?

Comment: `$(".css-class-with-your-background").removeClass("css-class-with-your-background") ; $(e.target).addClass("css-class-with-your-background")`

Comment: Yes.. When another button is color that color has to be appear in that button

Comment: $(e.target).css("background-color", "red"); I want to background color to disapper when another button is clicked and the same background should appear in the selected button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a CSS class to highlight the active button. You can reference the clicked button using the `this` keyword in the event handler to add the class. To remove the class from all buttons you can use the `buttons` collection.

If you put the latter logic in to its own function, then you can also call it on the `reset` event of the form.

Try this:

```js
let form = document.querySelector('#yourForm');
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-item');
let textbox = document.getElementById('display');

let setAllButtonsInactive = () => buttons.forEach(btn => btn.classList.remove('active'));

buttons.forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    textbox.value = e.target.value;
    setAllButtonsInactive();
    this.classList.add('active');
  })
});

form.addEventListener('reset', setAllButtonsInactive);
```

```css
button.active { 
  background-color: #C00;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<form id="yourForm">
  <fieldset>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" id="display" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
          <div class="input-group-btn">
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
              <button type="button" class="dropdown-item" value="1000">1000</button>
              <button type="button" class="dropdown-item" value="2000">2000</button>
              <div role="separator" class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <button type="button" class="dropdown-item" value="3000">3000</button>
              <div role="separator" class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <button type="button" class="dropdown-item" option value="4000">4000</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div><br><br>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="click to submit">
    <input name="reset" type="reset" value="Reset">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```